# Jquery NOTY update input or div in notification window?

Tags: jquery, noty

I'm displaying a NOTY with a message in it. I'd like to update the message shown, so the noty shows live updates.

I've tried this and the noty has a text input field with 'TEST' shown, but it never updates to say HELLO.

```
var n = noty({ type: 'information', layout: 'center', text: "<input id='msg' name='msg' value='TEST' />", 
dismissQueue: true, theme: 'relax', modal: true, maxVisible: 1 })

$('#msg').val('HELLO')
```

Can this be done ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://ned.im/noty/#/options):

```
new Noty({
   ...
   text: 'Some notification text',
   ...
 }).show();
```

The snippet:

```js
new Noty({
    type: 'information',
    layout: 'center',
    text: "<input id='msg' name='msg' value='TEST' />",
    dismissQueue: true,
    theme: 'relax',
    modal: true,
    maxVisible: 1
}).show();
$('#msg').val('HELLO')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/needim/noty/master/lib/noty.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/needim/noty/master/lib/noty.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see this works... just not sure why mine didn't.